# Load images into list in a specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with images that follow this name scheme:

> FEATURED_0.png
>
> FEATURED_1.png
>
> FEATURED_2.png

When I want to load them into a list usable by Pillow I do this:

```
for filename in glob.glob("FEATURED*.png"):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    featured_list.append(image)
```

This works pretty ok, but has a flaw. It loads the images, regardless of their number.
I already tried loading FEATURED_0 regardless of what, moving into a list and then checking if the next Image has a greater number +1, but that failed miserably.

So back to my question. Is there a way to load Images into a list in python, but in a specific order?

Comment: You could sort the result from the call to `glob`?

Comment: maybe use `sorted()`  - but it may gives `_10` before `_2` and it would need to convert string `"10"` `"2"` to integers and sort it - `sorted()` has option `key=` to assign function to special sorting. OR write own method to sort list with names. `glob` can't sort this. `os.listdir()` also can't sort filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob` doesn't have option to sort filenames. `os.list()` and `os.walk()` also can't sort it.

You have to use `list = sorted(list)` for this

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob("FEATURED*.png")):
```

But `sorted()` without parameters will put `_10` before `_2` because it checks char after char and first it compares `_` with `_` and next `1` with `2` and skip rest.

You may need to use `sorted(..., key=your_function)` with `your_function` which extracts number from filename and converts to `integer` - and `sorted` will use only this `integer` to compare names.

```
def number(filename):
    return int(filename[9:-4])

data = ['FEATURED_0.png', 'FEATURED_1.png', 'FEATURED_2.png', 'FEATURED_10.png']

print(list(sorted(data)))              # `_10` before `_2`
print(list(sorted(data, key=number)))  # `_2` before `_10`
```

Result

```
# `_10` before `_2`
['FEATURED_0.png', 'FEATURED_1.png', 'FEATURED_10.png', 'FEATURED_2.png']

# `_2` before `_10`
['FEATURED_0.png', 'FEATURED_1.png', 'FEATURED_2.png', 'FEATURED_10.png']
```

---

```
def number(filename):
    return int(filename[9:-4])

for filename in sorted(glob.glob("FEATURED*.png"), key=number):
    # ... code ...
```

---

You may also write it with `lambda`

```
sorted( data, key=(lambda x:int(x[9:-4])) )
```

---

You can create function which returns something more complex - ie. tuple `(extension, number)` - and then first you get all `.jpg` (sorted by number) and next all `.png` (sorted by number)

---

**EDIT:**

If you have filenames with different words but all has structure `word_number.extension` then you can use `split("_")` to get `word` and `split(".")` to get `number` and `extension`. And it may need to use tuple `(word, int(number))` to sort firt by `word` and next by `number`

```
def number(filename):
    word, rest = filename.split('_')
    number, ext = rest.split('.')
    return (word, int(number))

data = [
    'FEATURED_0.png', 'TEST_10.png', 
    'FEATURED_1.png', 'TEST_1.png', 
    'ANOTHER_10.png', 'FEATURED_2.png', 
    'ANOTHER_1.png', 'FEATURED_10.png',
]

print(list(sorted(data)))              # `_10` before `_2`
print(list(sorted(data, key=number)))  # `_2` before `_10`
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really good for my FEATURED png's, but for some reason not for any other images. I have the same amount of images in the same directory named TEST_number.png but when I replace FEATURED with TEST in the for loop I get this: `for filename in sorted(glob.glob("TEST*.png"), key = (lambda x:int(x[9:-4]))):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` So why does it do that? I only changed the name.

Comment: ... and I just found out why it doesn't work. It has to do with x[9:-4]. I just needed to change the 9.

Comment: I created code specially for filenames in your question - `"FEATURED*.png"`. For different names it may need different code. If you have all names with `_` then you can use `split("_")` - something like `filename.split('_')[0][:-4]`. But if you have different words in filename - `word_number.png` - then maybe you should use tuple `(word, int(number))` to sort first by `word`, and next by `number`.

Comment: in answer I added example with differen words in filenames. For more complex filenames you may need `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start with `0`, load each subsequent number, and stop when you hit a number that's not there, use a `while` loop:

```
num = 0
base = "FEATURED_%d.png"
while os.path.isfile(base % num):
    featured_list.append(Image.open(base % num))
    num += 1
```